# Can't get GLEW to work with VS2012

Tags: opengl, linker, sfml, glew

I have been trying to figure this out for hours but with no luck:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_glBegin@4 referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_glEnd@4 referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_glFlush@4 referenced in function _main
error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Pretty standard errors for linking, but I tried everything that came to my mind without luck unfortunately.

My setup is as follows:

- SFML 2.0 as the window manager
- GLEW 1.90 as the OpenGL extension manager
- SFML is working, so it's correctly linked etc...
- I have included GLEW include and library directories, I have also added glew32d.lib to the Additional Dependencies + added the glew32d.dll to the Debug folder (where the .exe resides)
- I also built GLEW from source, so it should work :S

Comment: Are linking against `opengl32.lib`?

Comment: These are OpenGL functions, not GLEW functions.

Comment: *sigh*, STUPID ME! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLEW stands for "OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library".  It doesn't define core OpenGL functions like `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. Are you also including your `opengl32.lib`, `glu32.lib`, and `glut32.lib` libs?

Comment: Yup, stupid me :(
I don't think I need to include glut32 right? I am using SFML as a window manager.

Comment: Yup. If you already have a window manager, you're good without glut.